# Snapping issue in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image][image]I had drafted a polyline with QGIS, I want to continue that line with snapping from it's end, but snapping is not working in starting, after starting I am getting snapping.[image]

Using windowsXp and Q gis 1.8.0

My issue is I had drafted a line and finished entering all attributes then i wan't to start a new line from the end point of first one there i didn't getting snapping.If i had started drafting with out snapping, second pic i can get snapping where i first wish to snap.

Comment: Could you please had some more information to your question. What version of QGIS are you using and in which Operative System. An image would also be nice.

Comment: Boss I had added more details please Help i am new person in Qgis

Comment: Everything should work just fine. Maybe ti was a bug in the 1.8 version. I have tried and it works fine in 2.2. Can you update your QGIS to the version 2.2 ?